# Isnt that true? Python x>y "<stdin>", line 1 and syntax error

Tags: python

Why I cant run that? If I run with indent, It says unexpected indent.

```
 x = 20
 y = 17
 while x > y
 print(x)
```

or

```
 x = 20
 y = 17
 while x > y
   print(x)
```

Comment: For starters, `while` conditions must end with a colon.

Comment: You forgot `:` after `while`, and it will be "perpetual loop"

Comment: And second, it's going to be an infinite loop. Nothing stop the while.

Comment: your print statement should be indented 4 spaces inside the while loop, the while statement should end with a colon, and also this will result in an infinite loop so I suggest adding a break statement before you run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a corrected version of your code. Of course, `x > y` will always be true, so the loop will run forever.

```
x = 20
y = 17
while x > y:
    print(x)
```

Comment: It says unexpected indent again.

Comment: Sorry, there's an extra space in the text. Edited.